# Spring 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' value incorrect

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websocket, dart, angular-dart

When connecting to a WebSocket from my frontend (using Stomp for Dart):

```
client = await connect(uri);
```

The client sends this key in the header:

```
Sec-WebSocket-Key: ydWCNEacB1ZqiHCH1Ip+vo4mhOw=
```

And receives a key back from the Spring WebSocket:

```
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: KVqExHty0Y5/fze11/EAhg==
```

This causes the client to throw:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://user:pass@localhost:8080/ws'
>   failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Incorrect
>   'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header value

I don't know how to calculate the correct response. But either way the client doesn't accept it for some reason.

How do I approach this problem? What could be causing the problem and how might I solve it?

Thanks

---

Edit: added websocket config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {


@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app").enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

Also

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketSecurityConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
    messages.anyMessage().authenticated();
    }
}
```

---

Edit: I found a wiki that describes how to calculate 'Sec-WebSocket-Key'. Following the guide below, it does look like the key is incorrect. This doesn't seem likely though or many more would be having issues.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

Comment: First of all show your code and then we will see together what is the problem

Comment: That's a bit of a problem. It's a large project and I have no idea what's causing the issue. As for the frontend, the connect(...) part above should be the only relevant part.

Comment: show us the config of your webSocket server

Comment: Edited message to add config.